# UFT shows "The operation cannot be performed" message when setting cell data in checkbox in Java Table

Tags: hp-uft, vbscript, uft-12.52, uft

UFT shows "The operation cannot be performed" message when setting cell data in Java Table:

```
JavaWindow("Name1").JavaDialog("Name2").JavaTable("Name3").SetCellData 8, 0, 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was in numeration of columns. I used `0` for the first column and received error. When numeration starts with `1` code runs just fine:

```
JavaWindow("Name1").JavaDialog("Name2").JavaTable("Name3").SetCellData 8, 1, 1
```

The same idea for `GetCellData` function.

**EDIT:** Application does not recognize state of checkbox (that it is checked) when it is set with `SetCellData` function (But checkbox looks like checked on the screen). Now I'm using `ClickCell` with checking that checkbox is not set:

```
isChecked = CInt(JavaWindow("Name1").JavaDialog("Name2").JavaTable("Name3").GetCellData(GetRow6, 1))
If isChecked = 0 Then
    JavaWindow("Name1").JavaDialog("Name2").JavaTable("Name3").ClickCell GetRow6, 1
End If
```